# TFS 2013 Build Failed with file not found exception but the file exist

Tags: build, tfsbuild

TFS2013 Build reports build failure with File not found exception.

But the file exists on the build agent. 
When I further investigated I found that TFS 2013 has removed one character from the file path. which causes the build to failure. 
example:

Actual path: D:\Builds\64\NBuildsMain\src\ClickWrap.resources\bin\x86\Debug**ClickWrap**.resources.dll

But the build system is looking for "D:\Builds\64\NBuildsMain\src\ClickWrap.resources\bin\x86\Debug**ClicWrap**.resources.dll"

could anyone help me to fix the issue, please?

Thanks,

Amal

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
You need to show how the build agent determines the path. Is any variable expanding involved for example? At a guess, somewhere there is a hard coded string with "Clic" instead of "Click".

Comment: in my further investigation, the length of the build definition is 12 charector and if I reduce it to 11 charector, the build succeeds. Not sure the cause for build failure yet...

Comment: Can you share the detailed build logs?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you are encountering the long path issue--path 260 character limit.

Even though the path length limitation is really annoying, the most effective and  easy way still is spending some time **tweaking your *file/folder structure*** to make this work. Just like the way in your comment, reduce the length of your build definition. You could also take the advice of this blog for doing such thing: [TFS Path Too Long problems](https://alistairbmackay.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/tfs-path-too-long-problems/)

For the long path issue in TFS, there had been a related uservoice and now completed.

> [Fix 260 character file name length limitation](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4954037-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation)
>
> We’ve removed the limitation from the BCL for the basic file
>   manipulation functionality (CRUD). You can find more details here:
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/
>
> *Immo Landwerth Program Manager .NET*